# Is it OK if I can feel fiberglass cloth texture after curing?

Tags: repair, fiberglass

I'm restoring a popup camper (not technically home improvement, I guess, but the question overlaps just fine) and I covered up some holes in the aluminum roof with Bondo-brand fiberglass cloth and resin. The repair went pretty well and everything seems structurally solid and well-adhered (I ground the area around the holes down to bare aluminum and cleaned it with acetone afterwards, so it should be solid). However, in a couple of places, I can still feel the texture of the fiberglass cloth on the exterior of the repair, whereas other places had enough resin on top to be smooth.

I've sanded everything down so that it should be fairly smooth and well-feathered once I put some paint on there. However, I'm wondering if there's any reason to put another coat of fiberglass resin on top of the places where I can still feel the texture of the fiberglass cloth?

I don't care about the aesthetics so much, it's more of a longevity/structural question.

I've tried Googling, but I haven't found anything specifically mentioning this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perfectly normal, and unless you have some need for it to be smooth, not a problem. Many less-fancy fiberglass products have the fabric texture exposed.

The bigger concern for longevity is then covering that material (which is highly subject to sun damage) with an adequate layer of paint to protect it from the sun.

Since you mention that you are preparing for paint, sounds like you'll have that covered.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! Should a coat or two of Rustoleum-brand spray paint be enough?

Comment: As long as it stays put, yes. When (or if, but probably when) it starts to degrade/peel/flake it needs to be replaced, but that might be after you are done with the old pop-up.